# Why recyclerView's avatar didn't change to new avatar after changed FirebaseUser's photoUrl?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

Why after I changed avatar from FirebaseUser's photoUrl and set avatar url to each Firestore's avatarUrl of uploadedImages, but all post recyclerView's avatar didn't change to new avatar from Firestore's avatarUrl of uploadedImages?

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_CHOOSE_AVATAR) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                if (data != null) {
//                    val user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
                    val uri = data.data

                    val avatarRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference
                        .child("userAvatar")
                        .child(user!!.uid)
                        .child(uri.toString())

                    avatarRef.putFile(uri!!)
                        .continueWithTask {
                            if (!it.isSuccessful) {
                                it.exception?.let {
                                    throw it
                                }
                            }
                            avatarRef.downloadUrl
                        }.addOnCompleteListener {
                            if (it.isSuccessful) {
                                val avatarDownloadUrl = it.result
                                val userProfileChangeRequest = UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                                    .setPhotoUri(avatarDownloadUrl)
                                    .build()

                                user?.updateProfile(userProfileChangeRequest)
                                    ?.addOnCompleteListener { it1 ->
                                        if (it1.isSuccessful) {
                                            Picasso.get()
                                                .load(user?.photoUrl)
                                                .transform(CropCircleTransformation())
                                                .into(avatar_url)
//TODO Change all post avatar
                                            FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
                                                .collection("uploadedImages")
                                                .whereEqualTo("uid", user?.uid)
                                                .addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, firebaseFirestoreException ->
                                                    if (querySnapshot != null && !querySnapshot.isEmpty) {
                                                        for (doc in querySnapshot.documents) {
                                                            Log.d(
                                                                TAG,
                                                                "uploadedImages's doc: ${doc.data}"
                                                            );
                                                            doc.data?.set(
                                                                "avatarUrl",
                                                                user?.photoUrl.toString()
                                                            )
                                                        }
                                                    } else {
                                                        firebaseFirestoreException.toString()
                                                    }
                                                }
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by myself. 
Solution is below.

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
                                                .collection("uploadedImages")
                                                .whereEqualTo("uid", user?.uid)
                                                .addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, firebaseFirestoreException ->
                                                    if (querySnapshot != null && !querySnapshot.isEmpty) {
                                                        for (doc in querySnapshot.documents) {

                                                            doc.reference.update("avatarUrl",user?.photoUrl.toString())

                                                        }
                                                    } else {
                                                        firebaseFirestoreException.toString()
                                                    }
                                                }
```